# How to zero values in array based on array with values to replace

Tags: python

I have array with values sourceArray and I have array with values to replace toReplace. I want to replace all values that are in sourceArray that are equal to values in toReplace array.

Is there some smart way to do it in Python ?

E.g.

```
 sourceArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7]
 toReplace = [5,6]
```

After replace I want to have

```
 sourceArray = [0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0,7]
```

Comment: Why not just iterate on your first array (sourceArray) and when the index of i == toReplaceArray[j], then you transform it to 0? In this, you'd need one loop and one inner loop *

Comment: I feel that there is a smarter way to do it in Python :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

List comprehension with conditional expression:

```
[0 if i in toReplace else i for i in sourceArray]
```

If the `toReplace` list is too big, it's preferable to make it a `set` to get O(1) lookup.

**Example:**

```
In [21]:  sourceArray = [0,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,7]
    ...:  toReplace = [5,6]
    ...: 

In [22]: [0 if i in toReplace else i for i in sourceArray]
Out[22]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0, 0, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

you Can use list comprehensions:

```
 new_list = [x if toReplace.count(x)==0 else 0 for x in sourceArray]
```